# Automapper and nested records

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to map an XML fragment to a record and its nested record. I assume I have to use `ConstructUsing()` in order to be able to supply all required constructor parameters.

In the `CreateMap` for `parent` I don't know how to specify the second parameter without going into some kind of re-entrant hell? I'm guessing I have to reference the mapper that's created in my `Startup.cs` perhaps. Then I could specify: `return new ParentRecord(ele.Attribute("id").Value, mapper.Map<ChildRecord>(ele));`.

#### XML Fragment

```cs
XElement xe = new XElement("root",
        new XElement("parent",
            new XAttribute("id", "123"),
            new XElement("child", "some text")));
```

#### Records

```cs
public record ParentRecord(long Id, ChildRecord Child);

public record ChildRecord(string Text);
```

#### Mapping Configuration

```cs
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<XElement, ChildRecord>()
            .ConstructUsing((ele, ctx) =>
            {
                return new ChildRecord(ele.Element("child").Value);
            });
        cfg.CreateMap<XElement, ParentRecord>()
            .ConstructUsing((ele, ctx) =>
            {
                
                return new ParentRecord(ele.Attribute("id").Value, ?WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE?);
            });
        });
    
    var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
```

#### Map Request

```cs
var o = mapper.Map<ParentRecord>(xe.Element("parent"));
```

Comment: `ctx.Mapper.Map<ChildRecord>(source)`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Nice! If you put as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the context mapper, smth like `ctx.Mapper.Map<ChildRecord>(source)`.